# How do I get all my pages to be updated automatically when I update a page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, as I was making my website, I started to have many pages. So, I wanna ask today, if ya'll know anyway way how I can make a change to a page of my website, and those changes be apply to my other pages automatically. For example, if I make a change to my nav bar of my website, I don't wanna have to go to every single page and and do it manually, I wanna know if there is a way how I can make a change to the nav bar in one of the web page, and get the other pages get the updates automatically. I would very much appreciates any advice, thank you.

Comment: Normally you'd "include" common componetry, but a website can be crafted in may ways, so your question is terribly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write your navbar code into a separate file and include it wherever you need navbar. This way if you change the main navbar.php file it will reflect in every other page that includes navbar.php